# How to fix blurry image

Tags: css, html, image, twitter-bootstrap, gif

I created this test landing page using bootstrap: http://ubersnap.netai.net

If you visit the site and look at the iPhone screenshot you will see you can hardly read the text on the screen.

However, if you just resize the browser window and maximize the windows back to its original size, it is 100% sharp.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to make the picture be sharp the first time it loads instead of resizing the browser window?

The image is a GIF if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

try this css to make your image  edges crisp.

```
.crisp-edges {
    image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges;
    /* Firefox */
    image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges;
    /* Opera */
    image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
    /* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
    image-rendering: crisp-edges;
    -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor;
    /* IE (non-standard property) */
}
```

Comment: It's not the edges only which are blurry. Whole image is unsharp

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up different images for different screensizes. There are many ways to do this, the easiest is to use media queries and having different dimensions/versions of the same image.

[Some example code sited from smashingmagazine.com:](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-background-images/)

```
/* default screen, non-retina */
.hero #cafe { background-image: url("../img/candc970.jpg"); }

@media only screen and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* Small screen, non-retina */
    .hero #cafe { background-image: url("../img/candc290.jpg"); }
}
@media
only screen and (min-resolution: 2dppx) and (max-width: 320px) {
    /* Small screen, retina */
    .hero #cafe { background-image: url("../img/candc290@2x.jpg"); }
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width: 538px) {
    /* Medium screen, non-retina */
    .hero #cafe { background-image: url("../img/candc538.jpg"); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled across [this](https://tutorialsclass.com/code/css-code-to-fix-blurry-image-when-scaling-down/).

The first fix worked for me:

```css
img {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```